# OpenVPN Site-To-Site Setup: Client LAN to Server LAN succeeds, but Server to Client fails

Tags: openvpn, windows-server-2016, connection

Network setup:

AWS subnets

- 10.0.0.0/24
- 10.0.1.0/24
- 10.0.254.0/24

Home subnet: 10.62.5.0/24

OpenVPN subnet: 10.8.0.0/24

At AWS, there's an OpenVPN server running at 10.0.254.234 on Windows 2016.

At home:

- There's an OpenVPN running in client mode at 10.62.5.147, also on
  Windows 2016.
- My Mac lives at 10.62.5.114
- My LinkSys router lives at 10.62.5.1

So basically what I've constructed here is I guess what OpenVPN referred to in the docs as a "site-to-site" VPN.

Routes have been entered in all the appropriate places and things are working great. I can successfully connect from my Mac, for instance, to any of my servers at AWS. For example, it's common for me to use the web site 10.0.0.95:443 from my Mac. The fact that all Home=>AWS connections are working leads me to believe that all routing is set up correctly.

So what's the problem?

The problem is that I can't connect from the AWS hosts to the Home hosts. Examples:

- 10.0.0.95 => 10.62.5.114 (server to Mac@home): fail
- 10.0.0.95 => 10.62.5.147 (server to OpenVPN@home): fail
- 10.0.254.234 => 10.62.5.114 (OpenVPN@AWS to Mac@home): success!
- 10.0.254.234 => 10.62.5.147 (OpenVPN@AWS to OpenVPN@home): success!

So what I'm ending up with here is that the OpenVPN server at AWS seems to be able to connect to anything on the home network, presumably using 10.8.0.1 as a source address. But any of the other hosts at AWS (10.0.0.0/16) can't access the home network.

Again, reverse the connection direction and everything is good. Home hosts can connect to any AWS hosts with no problem.

This makes me think that the issue isn't routing related. Perhaps there's a firewall somewhere on the Home hosts or at AWS that are blocking the AWS->Home connections. To that end, I tried:

(1) Making sure that the network rules for the AWS hosts allow 'all traffic' outbound -- which is the default.

(2) Completely disabling the firewall on the OpenVPN@home machine.

(3) Ensuring that no firewall is running on the Mac. I don't believe I ever installed one in any case.

I'm stumped on this one. What should I investigate next?

**UPDATE:**

The failure cases are now resolved. I can now successfully connect from the AWS hosts to the Home hosts:

- 10.0.0.95 => 10.62.5.114 (server to Mac@home): now successful!
- 10.0.0.95 => 10.62.5.147 (server to OpenVPN@home): now successful!

**The nature of my question has now changed from finding a solution to understanding *why* the solution worked.**

**SOLUTION:**

I added an AWS security rule for the host at 10.0.254.234 (OpenVPN@AWS) that allows inbound connections for all traffic from 10.0.0.0/16.

This perplexes me. The OpenVPN server is simply being used as a router. Why would I need a security rule that opens up this server to all inbound connections *to itself* in order for a connection to be established from an AWS host to a Home host?